# Identical GET requests in CURL and Postman have different responses

Tags: curl, postman, php-curl

I have been trying to reconstruct an API call I made in POSTMAN in PHP CURL (and also CURL in the CLI).

The following request works in Postman:

[image]

...I get a 200 response.

However when I use the following in PHP:

```
<?PHP
$curl = curl_init();
$curlopt=array();
$curlopt[CURLOPT_URL] ='https://familysearch.org/platform/tree/persons/LVDH-ZZT/families.json';
$curlopt[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = 1;
$curlopt[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 12;
$curlopt[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = 0;
$curlopt[CURLOPT_FAILONERROR] = 0;
$curlopt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = 1;
$curlopt[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = 0;

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: BearerUSYS79A3702777********************';
$curlopt[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;

$curlopt[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = 'GET';
curl_setopt_array($curl,$curlopt);

echo curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

...I get a 401.

Same with CURL in the CLI:

```
curl -H "Authorization: BearerUSYS79A37027774***********************" \
https://familysearch.org/platform/tree/persons/LVDH-ZZT/families.json
```

Anybody have any ideas? The requests seem to be identical to me.

By the way, I have sent them from the same IP Address as the Postman request.

**More info**
As per @hanshenrik request, here is the verbose CURL output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 204.9.224.11...
* Connected to familysearch.org (204.9.224.11) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=Utah; L=Salt Lake City; O=Intellectual Reserve Inc.; OU=Intellectual+Reserve+Inc.; CN=*.familysearch.org
*    start date: 2015-06-01 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-06-05 12:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: familysearch.org matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /platform/tree/persons/LVDH-ZZT/families.json HTTP/1.1
Host: familysearch.org
Accept: */*
Authorization: BearerUSYS79A3702777*****************************

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Content-Location: /tree/persons/LVDH-ZZT/families
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2016 12:53:04 GMT
< Link: <https://ident.familysearch.org/cis-web/oauth2/v3/authorization>; rel="http://oauth.net/core/2.0/endpoint/authorize"
< Link: <https://ident.familysearch.org/cis-web/oauth2/v3/token>; rel="http://oauth.net/core/2.0/endpoint/token"
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Expect
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Warning: 400 FamilySearch "Unable to  read tf person."
< Warning: 199 FamilySearch Best Practice Violation: Should specify versioned media type in Accept header, e.g. one of [ "application/x-gedcomx-v1+xml", "application/x-gedcomx-v1+json", "application/atom+xml", "application/x-gedcomx-atom+json", "application/x-fs-v1+xml", "application/x-fs-v1+json" ].
< X-PROCESSING-TIME: 5
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Connection: Close
< 
* Closing connection 0
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : 401,
    "message" : "Unable to  read tf person.",
    "stacktrace" : "GET http://tf.prod.us-east-1.prod.fslocal.org/tf/person/LVDH-ZZT?oneHops=cards returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized:\n{\n\"401\": \"Unauthorized\"\n}"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: they're not equal. equal URL, sure, but different http headers, as setting CURLOPT_VERBOSE to 1 probably should reveal. what is the Headers in postman, and what is the output from CURLOPT_VERBOSE=1 ?

Comment: @hanshenrik - verbose output added to original question above....

Comment: Try sending the same data from both CLI and requests to http://httpbin.org/get and you could see the actual received differences

Comment: good, now show us the headers sent by Postman

Comment: I'm getting inconsistent behavior from the API - tonight (for whatever reason) it no longer accepts the token sent as a header as `Access: Bearer<token>` but it DOES accept the token as a GET parameter. Using the GET parameter worked last night in Postman, but not in PHP Curl. For now, I'm set...but I will post again if anything changes.